# How to print dynamic button text?

Tags: python, kivy

I have created the buttons dynamically in kivy. I want to print button text on on_release/on_press but when I am tapping the buttons. It's printing last element of the list while it should print text of button.

```
from kivy.app import App
from kivy.lang import Builder
from kivy.uix.floatlayout import FloatLayout
from kivy.uix.button import Button
from kivy.properties import ObjectProperty
from kivy.factory import Factory

kv = '''
MyWidget:
    box: box
    BoxLayout:
        id: box
'''


class MyWidget(FloatLayout):
    box = ObjectProperty(None)

    def on_box(self, *args):
        a = ['Apple',"samsung","green"]
     
        for i in a:
      
            
            self.box.add_widget(Button(text=str(i),on_press=lambda x:self.uk(str(i))))
            
         
   
    def uk(self,instance):
     
        print(instance)
    def on_release(self, *largs):
        app = App.get_running_instance()
        app.button_texts.append(self.text)
        print(self.text)
           

Factory.register('MyWidget', cls=MyWidget)


class LoopApp(App):
    def build(self):
        return Builder.load_string(kv)


LoopApp().run()
```

Answer (score 1):

That is a common problem when building `Buttons` in a loop. The fix is to use another variable in your `lambda` for the loop variable. Try using this in that loop:

```
    for i in a:
        self.box.add_widget(Button(text=str(i), on_press=lambda x, y=i: self.uk(str(y))))
```